# Issues with LAN Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux, networking

So, I've been trying to set up a game over LAN with my brother. We're both running our own accounts, both on the same network, using Update 1.6.4. However, I'm running on Linux Mint while he's running on Windows 7. When he sets up a LAN game, I can see it in the multiplayer menu but when I try to connect it gives me the error:

`io.netty.channel.connecttimeoutexception connection timed out:`

This is the only text on the screen, besides the cancel button. When I try to set up a LAN game, I click `Open to LAN` but it doesn't show up on his list of servers.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have both of you dropped whatever firewalls your OSs have?

Comment: Do you have a good wifi connection